# problem with empty email on third party emailjs

Tags: reactjs

everything is connected to and im reciveing email to my personal email but it is empty

tried to change the values but it is not working

i have tried every possible way to fix it but im getting no fix for it

```
//store variables
const formInitialDetails = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    message: "",
  };
// connection i have removed the credentials
emailjs
      .sendForm("*********", "**********", e.target, "**********")
      .then(
        (result) => {
          // Set status to show the success message
          setStatus({ success: true, message: "Message sent successfully" });

          // Show the popup
          setShowPopup(true);



          // Clear the form
          setFormDetails(formInitialDetails);
          setButtonText("Send");
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error("Email sending failed:", error.text);
          setStatus({ success: false, message: "Email sending failed" });

          // Show the popup
          setShowPopup(true);
          // Clear the form
          setFormDetails(formInitialDetails);
          setButtonText("Send");
        }
      );
```

```
//this is one of my form 
<Col size={12} sm={6} className="px-1">
                        <div className={`form-group ${errors.firstName ? "has-error" : ""}`}>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            value={formDetails.firstName}
                            placeholder={`${errors.firstName ? "Please enter your first name" : "First Name"
                              }`}
                            onChange={(e) => onFormUpdate("firstName", e.target.value)}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </Col>`
Hello {{to_name}},

You got a new message from {{formDetails.firstName}} {{formDetails.lastName}}:

First Name: {{formDetails.firstName}}

 Last Name: {{formDetails.lastName}}

 Email: {{formDetails.email}}

Phone: {{formDetails.phone}}

 Message: {{formDetails.message}}

Best wishes,
EmailJS team
```

and this is the email template